# React js webpack can't be installed

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Hello I have a problem with my webservice. After update all files from master fornt- doesn't work (I use react js, webpack, node js). When i try to start project 
I have something like this :

```
 Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projekt\crew\crew-ui\webpack.config.js:1:77)
        at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

So I try install webpack from console but I have next error:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto
    npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
    npm ERR! code E404
    npm ERR! 404 Not Found: React@latest

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\mtmi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-28T07_27_01_002Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Does your web service have a `package.json` with all dependencies listed? You could try to run `npm install` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I have two package.json and package -lock.json When I start npm install i have this: npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Projekt\crew\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Projekt\crew\package.json'

Comment: 404 Not Found: React@latest

Comment: That is a problem with your package.json or you are using a npm proxy which is redirecting to a 404.

Comment: problem resolved i need to reinstall webpack